# ggplot2: x axis breaks doesn't work with 7 days breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to figure it out why this function for x axis breaks works perfectly for 2 to 6 days breaks, but gives me an error when I change to 7 days (Error: `breaks` and `labels` must have the same length). Thank you

Data Frame

```
library(tidyverse)

    df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = "day"))
    df$counts <-sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = 365, replace = TRUE)

    df<- df %>%
    mutate(date = as.Date(date),
           counts = as.numeric(counts))
```

Code

```
    breaks_daily = seq(from = min(df$date), to = max(df$date), by = "1 day")

    # Then make the 7 days interval labels 
    labels_7_days = format(seq(from = min(df$date), to = max(df$date), by = "7 days"), "%b-%d")
    labels_final = c(sapply(labels_7_days, function(x) {
      c(x, rep("", 6))
    }))
    #

     if ((length(breaks_daily) %% 7) == 0) {
        labels_final <- labels_final
      } else {
        labels_final<- labels_final[-length(labels_final)]
     }

    myplot <- ggplot(df, 
                       aes(y = counts, x = date)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", fill = "#99CCFF", width=1) +
      labs(x="Date", y="Quantity of Fruits") + 

      scale_x_date(labels = labels_final, breaks = breaks_daily, expand=c(0,0)) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 70), 
                         breaks = seq(0, 70, 10),
                         expand = c(0, 0)) +
      ggtitle(paste0("Figure 2: Fruits Example" )) +


      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, size = 35),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 35),
            axis.text = element_text(size = 35),
            axis.title = element_text(size = 40, face="bold"),
            axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = -2), 
            axis.title.x =  element_text(vjust = -1),
            axis.ticks.length = unit(.5, "cm"))


    myplot
```

Comment: Could you maybe also post a version where you said it would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but why don't you just use the inbuilt functionality? Sometimes it is not necessary to reinvent the wheel... ?

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = "day"))
df$counts <-sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = 365, replace = TRUE)

ggplot(df, aes(y = counts, x = date)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 week",date_labels = "%b %d")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

**update**

Here how to keep the ticks in-between (although I don't think your visualisation gains a lot with it)
You need to bring the two vectors to the same length. When using your label creator, you are creating six empty spaces for each week until the maximum (and including it!), then of course making "too many labels". Just subset the vector by using only the length of your breaks.

P.S. `geom_col` is identical to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")` , and in your example you don't need `position = position_dodge`, as you have no group defined. This argument only makes sense when you are dodging by a group.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2019-12-31"), by = "day"))
df$counts <-sample(seq(from = 20, to = 50, by = 5), size = 365, replace = TRUE)


breaks_daily <- seq(from = min(df$date), to = max(df$date), by = "1 day")

labels_7_days <- format(seq(from = min(df$date), to = max(df$date), by = "7 days"), "%b-%d")
labels_final <- c(sapply(labels_7_days, function(x) {
  c(x, rep("", 6))
})) [1:length(breaks_daily)] #that is the crucial bit

ggplot(df, aes(y = counts, x = date)) +
  geom_col(fill = "#99CCFF", width=1) + 
  labs(x="Date", y="Quantity of Fruits") + 
  scale_x_date(labels = labels_final, breaks = breaks_daily, expand=c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Tjebo, Thank you for your help. Because it doesn't show the ticks in between. Unfortunately, I need these daily ticks. :(

Comment: Hi Tjebo, this is perfect! Thank you very much. Yes, you're right. I don't gain much with the ticks in this chart, but that's not the real data, just made up data. In real world, it makes sense. Also, I thought this part would make them the same length if ((length(breaks_daily) %% 7) == 0) {
        labels_final <- labels_final
      } else {
        labels_final<- labels_final[-length(labels_final)]
     }. This part works fine. When I check the values of the variables, the formula works, but it just doesn't plot.